# Filtering out round-shaped blobs

Tags: python, opencv

[image: Image with noise(round-shaped small blob)strong text]

I need to remove round-shaped small blobs from my images.
I tried Blob Detector with different parameters, but never identifies it.
Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params() 
# Change thresholds
# params.minThreshold = 10
# params.maxThreshold = 200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = False
params.minArea = 1
params.maxArea = 100000000

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.minCircularity = 0.8

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.minConvexity = 0.5

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = False
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01


detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(image)
print(keypoints)
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=80)
plt.imshow(im_with_keypoints)
```

IS there any other way to filter out these small blobs, which are artifacts in reality?

Comment: By the looks of it I would try inverting your image as you seem to be looking for dark blobs instead of white ones

Comment: the screenshot of a plot with axes is nice and all, but you might wanna provide source data too, so people can try your code ([mre]) -- connectedComponents, then do your own filtering, and erasing (calculate mask from labels map and label to remove)

Comment: Use Skimage regionprops to get the eccentricity. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops a circle has eccentricity=1.